# Display string beside the y axis tool tip value

Tags: javascript

I have a standard series of time as x values, and their corresponding values as y axis like this :

```
dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2021,10,20), y: 1 },
        { x: new Date(2021,10,21), y: 3 },
    { x: new Date(2021,10,22), y: 2 },
          ...
            ]
```

Now I’d like to add different string like (2,3) to each y Tool Tip value, like this :

```
22 Oct 20 : 1 (5)
22 Oct 21 : 3 (1,4,3)
22 Oct 22 : 2 (2,3)
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: What library are you using for the charting?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.